# Show hide div and apply css rule in KnockoutJS with boolean value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to do two dynamic actions with KnockoutJS.

First, I want to apply specific css rule if the value is true, and also I want to toggle visibility of table row again checking the same value, if its true, then display the div.

This is what I have:

```
<th class="name" data-bind="css: { text_linethrough: !$root.HasDiscount() }, text: '$' + (Price)"></th>

<tr data-bind="visible: $root.HasDiscount(), css: { package5_Discount_Background: Name == 'Cady Kids Package 5' }">
                                        <th class="name" style="width: 60% !important;"><span></span>&nbsp;
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="name">
                                            PRE-ORDER PRICE:&nbsp;
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="name" data-bind="text: '$' + (Price - 10)"></th>
                                    </tr>
```

So, if the $root.HasDiscount() returns true, then I'm expecting that both the css will be applied, and the table row will be visible.

Although, the value is true, I'm still not getting the correct css rule and the row is still not visible.

This is how HasDiscount value is created:

```
t.HasDiscount = ko.computed(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/Shopping.asmx/checkShowDiscountedPrice",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (i) {
                        if (i.d) {
                            return i.d;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (n) {
                        u(n);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

Comment: @segFault still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be making an ajax call inside the computed like that.  It is an asynchronous call which means the function returns before the call to the server has made the round trip causing the return false that fires at the end to always fire.

You could try

```
t.HasDiscount = ko.computed(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/Shopping.asmx/checkShowDiscountedPrice",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (i) {
                        if (i.d) {
                            return i.d;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (n) {
                        u(n);
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
```

but I doubt that is a best practice

I would call make the ajax call separately and when it returns update an observable value.  Then return that observable property in the computed.

```
function someOtherFunction(){
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/webservices/Shopping.asmx/checkShowDiscountedPrice",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (i) {
                        if (i.d) {
                            t.HasDiscount (i.d);
                        } else {
                            t.HasDiscount (false);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (n) {
                        u(n);
                    }
                });
}

t.HasDiscount = ko.observable(false);
```

Comment: tried both of your examples but it didn't work, thanks for your help though

Comment: first example was questionable, but the second should of worked, I would use the Chrome KNockout debugger (if you use chrome that is) to inspect the binding and see what the binding values are at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

Comment: with the second example I'm getting undefined for HasDiscount https://i.gyazo.com/314c9e789f3ab2939f68b0787275882c.png

Comment: It should have a value if the ajax request is actually firing.    I made a small change to my second example (realized the computed was redundant).  I would check that the ajax request is firing.  It seems to me like it is not

Comment: Actually its not firing with the second example, you're correct

Comment: feel free to upvote and mark as correct when it starts working :)

Comment: the ajax call was working how I had setup initially, what do you think has changed using your example? Thx :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85338/discussion-between-qbm5-and-laziale).